How to use an existing browser for Playwright web scraping?
I am building a web scraper with Python and Playwright, and I’m facing two related challenges:

Playwright requires a separate browser (e.g., Chromium) to be included, which makes my packaged executable very large.
I want to reuse an existing browser installation on the user’s PC to avoid login prompts (e.g., by reusing an existing user profile).

Here’s the relevant part of my code:
async with async_playwright() as p:
    browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = await browser.new_context()
    page = await context.new_page()
    await page.goto("https://example.com")
    # Further scraping logic here

Is it possible to:

Use an already installed browser (e.g., Chrome or Edge)?
Reuse an existing user profile for login sessions?

This would help me avoid packing a browser and solve the login prompt issue. Any guidance would be appreciated!

These are two separate problems, both solvable through the docs and existing questions. Try executable_path and user_data_dir.

You need to manually start it with --remote-debugging-port=9222 params and then connect with http or ws. See connectOverCDP docs

example in JS with HTTP:

const browser = await chromium.connectOverCDP('http://localhost:9222');


example in Python with WebSocket:

browser = p.chromium.connect_over_cdp("ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/387adf4c-243f-4051-a181-46798f4a46f4")
    

